# Django 1.8.3 adding ForeignKey for existing database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I'm following the Django Tutorial 4 for adding permissions to my API resources.
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/

I have an existing database in Postgres which I'm able to read/write values using Django API. Now that I want to add permissions via User.auth which needs the addition of an extra column in DB. I get the following error when browsing API:

```
ProgrammingError at /server/
column server.owner_id does not exist
```

---

This is my Server model:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    discovered = models.BooleanField()
    status = models.SmallIntegerField()
    serialnumber = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    
    fk_server_model = models.ForeignKey('ServerModel', db_column='fk_server_model')
    fk_licensing = models.ForeignKey(Licensing, db_column='fk_licensing', blank=True, null=True)
    fk_network_services = models.ForeignKey(NetworkServices, db_column='fk_network_services', blank=True, null=True)
    fk_network_interfaces = models.ForeignKey(NetworkInterfaces, db_column='fk_network_interfaces', blank=True, null=True)
    fk_server_authentication = models.ForeignKey('ServerCredentials', db_column='fk_server_authentication', blank=True, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='servers')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Server, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'server'
```

As part of the tutorial, I want Django to the Foreign key field **owner_id** but after doing a:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

My database table Server doesn't have add the field not the foreign key relationship with the Auth_user table. What's the right way to have Django auto generate the foreign keys in database? I tried:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

With similar results
Thanks

Comment: in recent version of Django, you probably want to do `manage.py migrate` instead - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/

Comment: Is `auth` one application defined by yourself, or do you mean: `owner = models.ForeignKey('django.contrib.auth.models.User', related_name='servers')`?

Comment: auth is just a copy/paste from tutorial, I used 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'  and now I get: ERRORS:
api_app.Server.owner: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'django.contrib.auth.models.User', which is either not installed, or is abstract.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the field manually in DB. owner_id type int4 into my table and create the FK reference